# Extraer datos de un plc mitsubishi con python

Tags: python, conexión, tcpip, read, modbus

Estoy tratando de obtener datos de un plc Mitsubishi FX5u sin utilizar un servidor OPC el cual he investigado y podría conectarme por medio de modbus tcp, pero no logro hacer que se conecte con el

Este es el codigo utilizado, por el momento solo es lo mas basico para poder obtener la conexion

```
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.3.40')
client.write_coil(1, True)
result = client.read_coils(1,1)
print(result.bits[0])
```

La configuracion de mi ip ya esta dentro del rango de la de mi plc además aquí defino mi conexión modbus dentro del plc

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algun ejemplo o material seria util para poder realizar mi conexion para despues extraer los datos

Comment: No tengo nada para poderte responder formalmente pero no sé si sería algo como lo que hacen [acá](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5OPAigxsCY).

Comment: no es lo que busco, es mas enfocado a la conexión con Python pero muchas gracias por tu aporte compañero

Answer (score 0):

aunque no trabajo con python, te puedo recomendar que descargar de https://www.win-tech.com/. el simulador esclavo de modbus modsim.

con el puedes inicialmene comprobar si lo que tienes hecho funciona.dicho soft es muy sencillo de configurar, solo seleccionar el modo de conexion en tu caso tcip ya tiene por defecto el puerto 502.
abrir una ventana nueva y seleccionar la funcion que necesitas en tu caso la #1, la direccion del registro deseado y listo.

cambiar en tu script client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.3.40') a client = ModbusTcpClient('127.0.0.1') y ejecutarlo.

si todo va bien, no deberias tener problema con el plc.

saludos
luis lopez

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).